# Oracle AQ dequeue messages with certain headers

Tags: oracle-aq

I have a "Process" and a "Process_DLQ" in Oracle. Messages which can not be processed will be forwarded to DLQ after max retry count. Each message has also a custom header with a cycle count.

What I would like to do in PL/SQL is to enqueue all messages back to the Process queue which have a cycleCount less than X. I didn't find a way to pass a message selector. 
Is there a way to just browse the messages without dequeuing them? I would only dequeue when the criteria matches. Same like what JMS Brower API allows us.